# ANTD pro table. how to change width of expandable "+" column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

ANTD pro table. how to change width of expandable "+" column?
I added expandable row to the table. But the "+" column width is very large and does not change.
I tried to use css selector

```
.ant-pro-table .ant-table-thead > tr > th .ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell {
     width: 5px!important;
     padding: 1px!important;
      }
```

[img example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvapQ.png)
but this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
col.ant-table-expand-icon-col {
  width: 5px !important;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-elbakyan-78sl9v?file=/styles.css